# Add & Increment the Key and Value in C# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

I'm creating a counter that counts the number of times each character occurs in a string and then prints the results to the console.

Let's use this sample string:

```
string myString = "The pen is mightier."
```

I want the results to be

```
T : 2
h : 2
e : 3
  : 2
p : 1
n : 1
i : 3
s : 1
m : 1
g : 1
r : 1
. : 1
```

I've converted the string to a character array.

```
char[] charactersInString = myString.ToCharArray();
```

I've created a dictionary that stores the letters and the count.

```
Dictionary<char, int> letters = new Dictionary<char, int>();
```

I loop through each letter in the `characterInString` array and am not sure how to initialize and add a new pair when the dictionary doesn't contain the key or how to update the value only when it does contain the key?

Comment: dictionary has a ContainsKey function to check if a value exists, and an add function to add.. remember to init at 1 since once youre there you've found the first occurance :)

Comment: also notice the string has both 'T' and 't' and you count them as the same- but expect the first to appear in the dictionary - so you should check (ContainsKey(char.ToUpper()) || ContainsKey(char.ToLower()))...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy with LINQ.

```
var dictionary = myString.GroupBy( x => x ).ToDictionary( x => x.Key, x => x.Count );
```

If you want to count lower and upper case as the same, coerce the string to uppercase beforehand:

```
var dictionary = myString.ToUpper().GroupBy( x => x ).ToDictionary( x => x.Key, x => x.Count );
```

If you want to do it the traditional way, you'll need a loop.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<char,int>();
foreach (var character in myString.ToUpper())
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(character)) 
    {
        dictionary[character]++;
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary.Add(character, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: this would count 'T' and 't' as 2 different keys.. the expected result was 'T' : 2

Comment: This would add all values as UpperCase, for what they posted (add whatever appeared first) I think youd need to check both key options (ContainsKey(char.ToUpper()) || ContainsKey(char.ToLower()))

Comment: @audzzy I think you are inferring a requirement that the dictionary key, through its case, represent the case of the first occurrence of the letter, with subsequent occurrences counted in the same bucket regardless of their case. That does not seem like a useful requirement; indeed, it renders the dictionary difficult to use, because in order to get the count for a particular letter, you'd have to know its case ahead of time, or attempt to retrieve the count twice. I don't agree that is a better answer.

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question - I don't know the use case,  but if the result needed is the result in the post (and they actually bothered to capitalize the T), then it's a difference that I think should at least be put to notice.. even just for practice in c# case sensitivity is something one should deal with :)

Comment: whether or not it's "a better answer" depends on the requirements, I agree that the dictionary you posted might be easier to search- but the end result of what you posted is not what is posted under "I want the results to be" :)

Comment: The T/t was just a human typo and I understand the ToUpper and ToLower chaining methods.  Can @JohnWu help me understand what `dictionary[character]++;` does?

Comment: It increments the value for the entry with key character, like writing: dictionary[character] = dictionary[character]  + 1;